# Download images in chrome without sending a server request

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is an image I am trying to download, but since it is dynamically generated, everytime I try to download it I get a different image. Is there a way to download the image without sending a request to the server, but instead saving the client copy? (Chrome Extension)

Edit: preferably without having to screenshot or the like

Answer (score 1):

You could try copying the image and pasting it in MSPaint to avoid sending a request to the server.

I also noticed that if you save an image from an HTML page it sends a request for the file but if you open the image in a new tab (open image instead of a webpage) and then save the image it doesn't send a request to the server while saving, although it still sends a request for open image in new tab.

Comment: It seems in this case even if I open in new tab and save it, it downloads a different image